# How to validate bulk emails in typescript using mailgun?

Tags: angular, typescript, mailgun

I want to validate a list of email addresses using mailgun's api but keep getting the response jobs[]. I am not sure how I should do it.

I have managed to validate a single email address using the code below, but now want to validate emails within an array

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-validation',
  templateUrl: './email-validation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-validation.component.scss']
})
export class EmailValidationComponent implements OnInit {
    url: string;

    authorizationData = 'Basic ' + btoa('api' + ':' + 'XXXXXX');

    private headerOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.authorizationData
        })
    };

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {   }

    validateEmail(){
        this.url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v4/address/validate?address=emailAddressToValidate";

        this._http
            .get(this.url, this.headerOptions)
            .subscribe(
                data => { // json data
                    console.log('Success: ', data);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                });
    }
}
```

I want to use this url "https://api.mailgun.net/v4/bulk" to validate a list of emails in a given array but am lost as to what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any help

Comment: [`Bulk Validation allows for the validation of a list of email addresses. Given a list name and an uploaded file of email addresses, a backend processing job will be run to validate the list. Once the validations have all been completed, the results will be provided with download links.`](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-email-validation.html#bulk-validation) Have you provided a file of email addresses ?

Comment: I have read that from their site. Do I necessarily have to first list the emails in a file? Cant I just provide an array of emails?

Comment: Well usually when you use an API, you're supposed to listen to it to make it work ... And I do't know, I have simply given you the API doc, I have never used it personally. But it doesn't seem like it, no.

Comment: Which is actually justifiable, since Urls have a max length, meaning you would have limitations if you provided a list of emails.